# Eclipse VisualSVN error svn E175002: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, visualsvn-server, subversive

So this error seems to occur when I attempt to add a new repository location in Eclipse. However, I am sure that the URL and authentication info (username and password) are valid. The error looks like this,

[image]

and it occurs when I use `https://localhost/svn/TestSVN` as the URL. I understand I replaced the name of my PC with `localhost` but the same error occurs when I use the name of my PC instead. When I installed TortoiseSVN and VisualSVN-Server, I didn't do any custom installations so for the most part, the installations relied on default settings. I also used all the default settings when building the repository, `TestSVN`. I've successfully downloaded all the Subversive SVN Team Provider tools as well as the SVN Connector (SVNKit 1.8.12) since I've successfully added other SVN respository locations, just not a VisualSVN one, to Eclipse. I'm not sure if it will help, but here's a screenshot of my VisualSVN,

[image]

I should also note that I have tried turning off my firewall as well as turning off skype or other applications that may interfere with port 443, but those options haven't done me much good.

**EDIT:** I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTiPePJuh6M) to configure SVN with Eclipse and right at 10:38 I follow exactly what the user is doing and get the error above once I enter the correct information and press "Next/Finish".

**EDIT 2:** This issue is now fixed in subversive for Eclipse Neon as of September 1st, 2016.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with Eclipse. I could reproduce it with clean installation of Eclipse Neon + Subversive.

Comment: I would report it to dev.eclipse.com. However, it seems that login and registration form is broken there at the moment. I can't login and file a report at the moment :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with eclipse neon except is says "for input String bf". I don't know what's wrong, but uninstalling SVN Team Provider and installing the version from mars software site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars) with SVNKit 1.7.14 worked for me.

Comment: Thank you good sir, downloading the mars version of subversive works!

Answer (score 1):

The bug has been fixed in 4.6.1.

---

It seems to be a new bug in Eclipse / Subversive or one of their components: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499529

If you experience the problem, vote for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499529, and wait for a fix.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, just voted. Looks like Ιώσηπος Μπεκενμπάουερ's answer will do for now because downloading the Mars version of subversive does work so this looks like a bug regarding the Neon version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I traced the problem back to changed certificate. The SVN client in eclipse was not able to process the string coming from SVN and asking to import and confirm the server certificate. In my case, in '... For input String "xx"...', the "xx" was actually the first part of the certificate in hexa. I went to commit with command line, responded 'p' (imported the cert permanently)  and voila eclipse SVN was working again.

Answer (score 0):

So in addition to the answer posted by Ιώσηπος Μπεκενμπάουερ, I found another way to avoid the error posted in my question. Besides downloading the Mars version of subversive, you can also use the path to the repository on your computer instead of the http link. For example, my repository named `TestSVN` was located in a folder called `Repositories` on the C drive so I used `C:\Repositories\TestSVN` as the URL instead. Note that this won't apply to every answer but if it does apply then it will work, but definitely follow Ιώσηπος Μπεκενμπάουερ's answer if this doesn't apply to you.

**EDIT:** This issue is now fixed in subversive for Eclipse Neon as of September 1st, 2016.

Comment: It works for local repos only. It won't help in 99% of cases because people mostly use http(s) to access repos.

Comment: @bahrep This is true but I've only experienced this issue with local repos as opposed to remote repos so far. Maybe someone will shed more light on this in the future.