# Subversive to SVN server connection failure

Tags: eclipse, svn

I just installed Eclipse Neon and added the Subversive SVN plugin. I tried to add a new repository location which I know is correct and all I get is:

- Using the SVNKit 1.8.12 SVN connector (which I always used before):
  `org.eclipse.team.svn.core.connector.SVNConnectorException: svn: E175002: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cd"`
- Using the Native JavaHL 1.8.15 SVN connector:
  `java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.decodeCertificateData(SVNUtility.java:126)`

None of these errors seem to be known by search engines. My SVN server is 1.8.10.

*PS : if it's offtopic because not specifically programmation-oriented, please indicate on which SE site I should post this.*

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534902/eclipse-visualsvn-error-svn-e175002-java-lang-numberformatexception

Comment: It seems to be a new bug in Subversive. Please report it to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Subversive&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All

Comment: Indeed bahrep, thanks. However do you have any idea about the second error (the one with the Native JavaHL connector)?
Also I see on the question you linked that you planned to report the bug. Did you manage to do so?

Comment: I've encountered both these errors with latest versions of Eclipse + Subversive. Getting the similar error, but the "input string" part is different. I didn't report this to their bugtracker because I was unable to register a new account or reset my password which I forgot. I haven't tried again yet.

Comment: Thank you for filing the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer myself. It is a bug, that I filled here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499529 and that has been fixed since then.
Now anyway a workaround is to use the SVN software from an old Eclipse repository such as Mars.